# Using if/switch/for conditions in test case

Tags: java, selenium, junit

I'm looking for the best practice to write test case in selenium using JUnit.

If some test is using a switch or if, should it be split to different test cases to avoid the conditions or using conditions in test is 'okay' 
 ? And Why?

Edit:
I need to know if you have the options to split a test case that is using if & switch to a smaller test to avoid using conditions in them, would you prefer to split it or you're ok using the conditions inside of your junit selenium test ?

Thank you :-)

Comment: Can you give an example of what you're currently doing? I'm not sure I understand what it is you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might help...

Tests should be SIMPLE.  FAST. INDEPENDENT. and IDEMPOTENT

If you have a large `switch` statement or `if` ladder, then Yes.  You should split them to different tests.  Consider the following: (this is using the [getting-started-with-selenium](http://github.com/ddavison/getting-started-with-selenium) framework)

```
@Test @Config(url="http://someurl.com", browser = Browser.CHROME)
public void myLongTest() {
  setText("#username", "some_username")
  .setText("#password", "some_password")
  .click("#btn-login")
  .store("some_variable", getText("#element");
  // some_variable will be "a" | "b" | "c"
  switch ((String) get("some_variable")) {
    case "a":
      click("#a")
      .validatePresent("#something");
      break;
    case "b":
      click("#b")
      .validatePresent("#something-else");
      break;
    case "c":
      click("#c")
      .validatePresent("#something-else-else");
      break;
  }
}
```

Instead of the long test, you *could* divvy this up into three different test cases, one for each, which by traditional standards would be good because the tests would then be faster.

```
@Test @Config(url="http://someurl.com", browser = Browser.CHROME)
public void myShortTest_CaseA() {
  setText("#username", "some_username")
  .setText("#password", "some_password")
  .click("#btn-login")
  .click("#a")
  .validatePresent("#something");
}

@Test @Config(url="http://someurl.com", browser = Browser.CHROME)
public void myShortTest_CaseB() {
  setText("#username", "some_username")
  .setText("#password", "some_password")
  .click("#btn-login")
  .click("#b")
  .validatePresent("#something-else");
}

@Test @Config(url="http://someurl.com", browser = Browser.CHROME)
public void myShortTest_CaseA() {
  setText("#username", "some_username")
  .setText("#password", "some_password")
  .click("#btn-login")
  .click("#c")
  .validatePresent("#something-else-else");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Test case should not have conditions because you should know the inputs apriori. The only condition I can think of when that isn't true, is if your testcase should be portable across different environments, so you would have branches in it depending on what environment it is executing in. However, even in that case it should test a single aspect of your program (e.g. in Selenium, you might write a test to click a button and check its effect). To test several aspects, write several test cases.